# Is a log(n) std::find_if possible?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, stl

I will define a class and use a container (possibly `std::set`) with a custom comparator function (basically, raw integer comparison on a class member variable). I wish to know if I can somehow keep this set `std::sort`ed and use `std::find_if` with logarithmic performance instead of naive linear searching.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::set` is an ordered container. It's already sorted with the comparator you provided. Just use its own [`std::set::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) member function.

With C++14 and above, you can even adjust the comparator in order to allow `find` to work with any type that is comparable to your elements, and respects the same order.

Comment: Afaik, find utilizes == as a comparator, and I can't overload it for pointers. That's why I will declare a custom comparator function (a getter of member int value).

Comment: @corsel - Your understanding is incorrect. `std::set::find` uses the same comparator you provided for the set.

Comment: @corsel ... and unless you use the same comparator to sort the set as you use for `find`, you have no chance to get O(logN)

Comment: Ah... I have been looking for a comparator function definition inside `std::find`, unaware that it is defined in `std::set` (in documentation). There is no need for `std::find_if` in that case. Thanks, I am marking this as answer.